# Load unity webgl only once in react

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, webgl

Currently i'm using [unity react webgl](https://react-unity-webgl.dev/docs/introduction) for connecting webgl to react application. And i want to load unity application only once and use it anywhere.

I'm currently coding like this but unity kept reloading whenever i change from **Unity1** screen to **Unity2**.

Is there anyway i can init **UnityApp** once and use it anywhere like singleton pattern?

**UnityApp.jsx**

```
const UnityApp = () => {
  const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "build/myunityapp.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "build/myunityapp.data",
    frameworkUrl: "build/myunityapp.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "build/myunityapp.wasm",
  });

  return <Unity unityProvider={unityProvider} />;
}
```

**Route.jsx**

```
const Route = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path='/' element={<Root />}>
        <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path='/unity1' element={<UnityPage1 />} />
        <Route path='/unity2' element={<UnityPage2 />} />
      </Route>
    )
  )

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

const Root = () => {;
  return (<div>
    root
    <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
    <Link to='/unity1'>Unity 1</Link>
    <Link to='/unity2'>Unity 2</Link>

    <Outlet />
  </div>)
}
```

**UnityPage1.jsx**

```
const UnityPage1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <UnityApp />
      <Link to='unity2' />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UnityPage2.jsx**

```
const UnityPage2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <UnityApp />
      <Link to='unity1' />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!